# Evaluate $ \int \frac{1}{\sin{x}\cos^{3}x}dx $

Tags: integration

$$ \int \frac{1}{\sin{x}\cos^{3}x}dx $$

$$\Rightarrow \int \frac{1}{\sin{x}\cos^{3}x}{\cos{x}\over \cos{x}}dx$$

$$\Rightarrow \int \frac{\sec^{4}{x}}{\tan{x}}dx$$

$$\Rightarrow \int \frac{\sec^{2}(1+\tan^{2}x)}{\tan{x}}dx$$

$$Substitution \tan{x}=t \Rightarrow \sec^{2}xdx=dt$$

$$\Rightarrow \int \frac{1+t^{2}}{t}dt$$

$$\Rightarrow \int \frac{1}{t}dt+\int tdt $$

$$\Rightarrow \log|t|+\frac{t^{2}}{2}+C$$

$$\Rightarrow \log|\tan{x}|+\frac{1}{2}\tan^{2}x+C$$

Any other elegant way to do this?

Comment: That looks pretty elegant to me! You could also do $\int \frac{\sin x}{(1-\cos^2x)\cos^3x} \,dx = \int \frac{du}{(u^2-1)u^3}$ and then use partial fractions; but I think this takes longer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way, I am not sure it is an elegant way but is different than yours
$$\int  \frac { 1 }{ \sin { x } \cos ^{ 3 } x } dx=\int { \frac { \sin ^{ 2 }{ x+\cos ^{ 2 }{ x }  }  }{ \sin { x } \cos ^{ 3 } x } dx= } \int { \frac { \sin { x }  }{ \cos ^{ 3 }{ x }  }  } dx+\int { \frac { 1 }{ \sin { x\cos { x }  }  } dx } =\\ =-\int { \frac { d\cos { x }  }{ \cos ^{ 3 }{ x }  } +\int { \frac { \sin ^{ 2 }{ x+\cos ^{ 2 }{ x }  }  }{ \sin { x } \cos { x }  }  }  } dx=\frac { 1 }{ 2\cos ^{ 2 }{ x }  } +\int { \frac { \sin { x }  }{ \cos { x }  } dx+\int { \frac { \cos { x }  }{ \sin { x }  } dx } = } \\ =\frac { 1 }{ 2\cos ^{ 2 }{ x }  } -\ln { \left| \cos { x }  \right| +\ln { \left| \sin { x }  \right|  } +C= } \frac { 1 }{ 2\cos ^{ 2 }{ x }  } +\ln { \left| \tan { x }  \right|  } +C$$

Comment: i didn't get the first integral of second line. What's $ d\cos{x} $? What you did there?

Comment: @mikealise, instead of making substitution as $$\\ \sin { xdx } =du\quad ,-\cos { x } =u\\ \int { \frac { \sin { x }  }{ \cos ^{ 3 }{ x }  }  } dx=-\int { \frac { du }{ { u }^{ 3 } }  }  $$ you can do this directly as i did.$$\int { \frac { \sin { x }  }{ \cos ^{ 3 }{ x }  }  } dx=-\int { \frac { d\left( \cos { x }  \right)  }{ \cos ^{ 3 }{ x }  }  } $$

Comment: how did $\int \frac{d\cos{x}}{cos^{3}x}$ simplify to $\frac{1}{2cos^{2}x}$

Comment: $$\sin { xdx } =du\quad ,-\cos { x } =u\\ \int { \frac { \sin { x }  }{ \cos ^{ 3 }{ x }  }  } dx=-\int { \frac { du }{ { u }^{ 3 } }  } =???\\ $$

Comment: cheers mate! that was helpful

Comment: you're welcome)

Answer (score 0):

This is not better than your solution but works:
\begin{eqnarray}
\int \frac{1}{\sin{x}\cos^{3}x}dx
&=&
\int \frac{\cos x}{\sin{x}\cos^{4}x}dx
&=&
\int \frac{du}{u(1-u^2)^2}dx
\end{eqnarray}